# What event is fired by Safari when the bottom sidebar disappears?

Tags: javascript, ios, events, safari

In Safari (iOS7, iOS8) a bottom bar is present at the loading off the page.

Once you scroll down, it disappear, switching the viewport to a greater height.

Is there an event fired by the browser that we can catch and use to execute some code (to take advantage of the greater space created) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [the `resize` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) :

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){ ...
```

Note that it also works on other browsers and with other devices every time some top or bottom bar appears or disappears.

Comment: I thought the event wasn't fired since make the web inspector in Safari working since I upgraded to iOS8 but a simple alert confirmed that it's probably my code that is buggy.
Thank you !